# PivotTable will not group ANYTHING

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have done some Googling and found other people had issues when their DATE fields were not true dates, had blank values, or where date values were not actual dates (e.g. `1/33/2015`). However, none of these are true for my table.

I am also unable to group regular text fields into a new group like I used to be - I am working with ticket closures and want to Group "Cancelled" and "Completed" tickets into a `Closed` group and then all else into an `Open` Group.

I was able to do this on another Excel sheet a few weeks ago but now the option is completely grayed out.

```
Count of ETC    Column Labels               
Row Labels  Closed-AS IS    Complete    New Pending Grand Total
John Doe    2   365         367
1/2/2015        2           2
1/5/2015        1           1
1/8/2015        1           1
1/15/2015       1           1
1/16/2015       1           1
1/20/2015       2           2
1/21/2015       2           2
1/22/2015       2           2
1/23/2015       1           1
1/26/2015       2           2
1/30/2015       1           1
2/2/2015        1           1
2/3/2015        2           2
2/4/2015        3           3
2/5/2015        1           1
2/6/2015        1           1
```

**EDIT:**
AHAH! Okay, so I've narrowed it down (still not resolved though). I am able to GROUP/UNGROUP utilizing an extrenal data source (in this case it's a .iqy file - or SharePoint List/Export). I am UNABLE to GROUP/UNGROUP when referencing a table defined on the actual workbook or on the Data Model.

Comment: We need more information - show a snippet of your raw data and a snippet of your pivot table.

Comment: Edited the OP with sample data.

Comment: I am and am not using the data model. I've tried both and no joy.

Comment: I DO have other PT's that were made beforehand that can still group/ungroup (they have existing groups)

Comment: AHAH! Okay, so I've narrowed it down (still not resolved though).

I am able to GROUP/UNGROUP utilizing an extrenal data source (in this case it's a .iqy file - or SharePoint List/Export). I am UNABLE to GROUP/UNGROUP when referencing a table defined on the actual workbook or on the Data Model.

Answer (score 0):

This is not much of an answer but here's what I found.

PowerPivot, apparently, does NOT allow for GROUPING/UNGROUPING so if your data is added to PowerPivot's data model these options will be grayed out. Instead, you will have to "force" the data by creating new columns with whatever grouping logic you can build in DAX and then create a hierarchy out of them.